# Link saturation/capacity optimization algorithm

Tags: algorithm, telecommunication, congestion-control, capacity-planning

My question is related to telecommunications, but it's still pure programming challenge since I'm using a Soft-switch.

Goal:

- create algorithm used by call routing engine to fully saturate
  available link capacity with traffic sold at highest possible rate

Situation:

- there is communications link (E1/T1) with fixed capacity of 30 voice
  channels (1 channel = one voice call between end users, so we can have max 30 concurrent calls on each link)
- link has fixed cost of running per month, so it's best when it's fully utilized all the time (fixed cost divided by more minutes results in higher profit)
- there are users "fighting" for link capacity by sending calls to Call Routing Engine
- each user can consume random link capacity at given time, it's possible that one user take whole capacity at one time (ie peek
  hours) but consume no capacity in off-peak hours
- each user has different call rate per minute
- ideal situation: link is fully utilized (24/7/365) with calls made by users with highest call rate per minute

Available control:

- call routing engine can accept call and send it using this link or reject the call

Available data:

- current link usage
- user rate per minute
- recent calls per minute per user
- user call history (access is costly, but possible)

Example:

- user A has rate 1 cent per minute, B 0.8 cent, C 0.7 cent
- it's best to accept user A calls and reject others if user A can fill full link capacity
- BUT user A usually can't fill whole link capacity and we need to accept calls from others to fill the gap
- we have no control on how many calls users will send at given moment, so It's hard to plan what calls to accept and what to reject

Any ideas or suggested approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the simplest algorithm you can come up with may be the best - for example if you get a call from user type B or C, simply check if there are any calls from a user type A and if not accept then call.

The reasosn why it may be best to go simplest approach:

- Tts easier!
- Rejecting calls like this may not be allowed by the regulator depending on the area.
- If there really is a strong business opportunity here then a VoIP solution is likely going to be easier and if your client does not ask you do this someone else will likely do it anyway. VoIP as a an alternative transport for high cost TDM legs of calls is a very common approach.